# Flatlist not updating until second refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist pointed towards a datasource in the state.  When I select a dropdown value, that changes the global redux store.  I am listening to any global store changes in this component and when the dropdown value changes it should fetch new data and update the list.

However, when I select a new dropdown value it fire off a new request, returns the correct data but this updated data isnt reflected in the list **until** I fire off another request, but then the data is only updated with the previous request and not the current.  Its as if the list is not re-rendering when the latest data arrives.

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: [],
        refreshing: false,
        numberOfCoins: props.numberOfCoins,
        currencyType: props.currencyType
    };

    this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
    this._getCoinData = this._getCoinData.bind(this);
    this._onRefresh = this._onRefresh.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._getCoinData();

    getStore().subscribe(() => {
        console.log('!!! trigger state refresh')
        this._onRefresh();
    });
}

async _getCoinData() {
    console.log('!! _getCoinData')
    const result = await getCryptocurrencyData();
    const adaptedResult = adaptCoinData(result);
    console.log('!! adaptedResult', adaptedResult[0].price)

    this.setState({
        data: adaptedResult,
        refreshing: false
    });

    console.log('!! refresh', this.state.refreshing)

}

_renderRow(data) {
    console.log('!! _renderRow', this.state.data[0].price)

    return (
        <CoinCell
            name={data.item.name}
            price={data.item.price}
            percentChange={data.item.percentageChange}
            symbol={data.item.symbol}>
        </CoinCell>)
}

_renderHeader() {
    return (
        <Header
            refresh={this._onRefresh}/>
    )
}

async _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    console.log('!! refresh', this.state.refreshing)
    await this._getCoinData();
}

_renderSeparator() {
    return (
        <View
            style={{
                height: 1,
                width: "100%",
                backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
            }}
        />
    );
};

render() {
    return (
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                extraData={this.state.data}
                onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
                refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                renderItem={this._renderRow}
                ListHeaderComponent={this._renderHeader()}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this._renderSeparator}
                keyExtractor={item => item.name}
            />
    );
}
```

}

Data snippet being set again `adaptedResult`

```
[ { name: 'Bitcoin',
    symbol: 'BTC',
    timePeriod: 2457981859.410431,
    percentageChange: 1.72,
    price: 4816.6364323507 },
  { name: 'Ethereum',
    symbol: 'ETH',
    timePeriod: 1008374905.5177627,
    percentageChange: 3.2,
    price: 341.3106575964 },
  { name: 'XRP'
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to check if the `id's` from `getCryptocurrencyData()` are unique?

Comment: They weren't but I've changed it to `keyExtractor={item => item.name}` and now the warning has disappeared, but the issue hasn't

Comment: Can you try checking the `data` inside `render()` before `return`, we can come to some conclusion on state updates if updated data is not appearing.

Comment: The data does not change its still the old data, until another `_onRefresh` is called again

Comment: when `adaptedResult` returns a result it is correct, when assigning the data to the state and logging the value out after calling `setState` it is also correct

Comment: can you add `import`s / code before `export class Home extends React.Component {` or if you can provide link to your codebase it'll be better.

Comment: Doesn't have latest commits (but those are in this thread)  https://github.com/jas1222/coincheckerrn/tree/feature/userFilters

Comment: Sorry to say, i went through the codebase and found it was poorly structured, i tried to replicate https://snack.expo.io/@srsandeepkumar/flatlist---so---check but it was very hard, check https://snack.expo.io/rkapfg5XX for simple one.

ideally Question has to be more precise and well structured on SO.

Comment: Sorry you found it unstructured, thought most of the relevant logic was in the `Home` file since I'm essentially doing a `GET` request and re-assigning the new data to the state and hoping the list would get updated (which its not)